# Big O of shrinking list?

Tags: math, big-o

Want to make sure I have this right.

```
int n = 20;
while (n > 0) 
   int index = 0
   while (index < n)
      index++
   n--
```

The Big O of this is:

```
n + (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + … ++ (n-n)
```

Is that still technically O(N)?

Answer (score 2):

Prove by induction:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n(n + 1) / 2
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = O(n^2)
```

Base case:

```
n = 1
1 = (1 + 1) / 2
1 = 2 / 2
1 = 1
```

Assume true up to `k` for `k < n`:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k = k(k + 1) / 2
```

Prove true for `n = k + 1`

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k + (k + 1) = (k + 1)(k + 1 + 1) / 2

k(k + 1)/2 + (k + 1)          = (k + 1)(k + 1 + 1) / 2

k(k + 1)/2 + 2(k + 1) / 2     = (k + 1)(k + 1 + 1) / 2

(k^2 + k)/2 + (2k + 2) / 2    = (k + 1)(k + 1 + 1) / 2

(k^2 + k + 2k + 2) / 2        = (k + 1)(k + 1 + 1) / 2

(k^2 + 3k + 2) / 2            = (k + 1)(k + 2) / 2

(k^2 + 3k + 2) / 2            = (k^2 + 2k + k + 2) / 2

(k^2 + 3k + 2) / 2            = (k^2 + 3k + 2) / 2
```

Therefore:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = n(n + 1) / 2
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = (n^2 + n) / 2
1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = O(n^2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you work it out, it's the Nth triangular number - and therefore:

```
O(N(N + 1) / 2)
```

Comment: Thank you. That is actually a final answer? Meaning, it doesn't simplify to anything less? It's ultimately O(n^2) isn't it?

Comment: No, it's not - `O(n^2)` with case of 10 goes to 100, whereas the 10th triangular number is `(10 * 11) / 2 = 110 / 2 = 55`. Big difference.

Comment: Really? The other guy posted below:
n(n + 1) / 2  = (n^2 + n) / 2 = O(n^2)

That's not correct?

Comment: O(N(N+1)/2) = O(N^2)

Comment: Erm, no - mathematics proves that the two are different: `7 ^ 2 = 49`, and the 7th triangular number is `7(7 + 1) / 2 = (7 * 8) / 2 = 56 / 2 = 28`, formed from `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7`.

Comment: Yes, technically it's `O(n^2)`.See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954109/why-do-we-ignore-co-efficients-in-big-o-notation). But we all get the point.

Comment: By [definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), `O(n(n + 1) / 2)`, `O(n^2 / 2)` and `O(n^2)` are all correct. You can claim `O(7 * n^2 + 1024)` is correct too. But by convention, we pick `O(n^2)`.