# How can i get the Big O Notations in this while loop?

Tags: c, big-o

The computational cost will only consider how many times `c = c+1;` is executed.

I want to represent the Big O notation to use **n**.

```
count = 0; index = 0; c = 0;
while (index <= n) {
   count = count + 1;
   index = index + count;
   c = c + 1;
}
```

I think if the "iteration of count" is `k` and "iteration of index" is `n`, then `k(k+1)/2 = n`.

So, I think O(root(n)) is the answer.

Is that right solution about this question?

Comment: Try running your code with various values of `n`. Then see what the relationship between those `n` values and the resulting `c` values is. That will be your complexity.

Comment: Yes, your question is more correct than the comments or answers. O(sqrt(n)) is correct for the reasons you give.

Comment: Oh, I see. thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is that right solution about this question?*

This is easy to test. The value of `c` when your `while` loop has finished will be the number of times the loop has run (and, thus, the number of times the `c = c + 1;` statement is executed). So, let us examine the values of `c`, for various `n`, and see how they differ from the posited `O(√n)` complexity:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    printf("    c   root(n)  ratio\n"); // rubric
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        int n = 10000000 * i;
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int c = 0;
        while (index < n) {
            count = count + 1;
            index = index + count;
            c = c + 1;
        }
        double d = sqrt(n);
        printf("%5d  %8.3lf %8.5lf\n", c, d, c / d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    c   root(n)  ratio
 4472  3162.278  1.41417
 6325  4472.136  1.41431
 7746  5477.226  1.41422
 8944  6324.555  1.41417
10000  7071.068  1.41421
10954  7745.967  1.41416
11832  8366.600  1.41419
12649  8944.272  1.41420
13416  9486.833  1.41417
```

We can see that, even though there are some 'rounding' errors, the last column appears *reasonably* constant (and, as it happens, an approximation to √2, which will generally improve as `n` becomes larger) – thus, [as we ignore constant coefficients in Big-O notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29954109/10871073), the complexity is, as you predicted, `O(√n)`.

Comment: Be aware, however, that _testing_ for several small values proves nothing about the asymptotic behavior for large values. And each tested value is _small_ compared to infinity... :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's first see how `index` changes for each loop iteration:

```
index = 0 + 1 = 1
index = 0 + 1 + 2 = 3
index = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
...
index = 0 + 1 + ... + i-1 + i = O(i^2)
```

Then we need to figure out how many times the loop runs, which is equivalent of isolating `i` in the equation:

```
i^2 = n =>
i = sqrt(n)
```

So your algorithm runs in `O(sqrt(n))` which also can be written as `O(n^0.5)`.

Comment: In the expression `floor(0.5) i^2` the first term `floor(0.5)` equals zero, Are you sure you've put parentheses correctly?

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks! Brainfart on my part. Fxed by omitting it as it wasn't particular important.  What I meant was  `floor(i/2) * i`.