# LeetCode 347 Solution Time Complexity Calculation

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I have been following Neetcode and working on several Leetcode problems. Here on 347 he advises that his solution is O(n), but I am having a hard time really breaking out the solution to determine why that is. I feel like it is because the nested for loop only runs until `len(answers) == k`.

I started off by getting the time complexity of each individual line and the first several are O(n) or O(1), which makes sense. Once I got to the nested for loop I was thrown off because it would make sense that the inner loop would run for each outer loop iteration and result in O(n*m), or something of that nature. This is where I think the limiting factor of the return condition comes in to act as the ceiling for the loop iterations since we will always return once the answers array length equals k (also, in the problem we are guaranteed a unique answer). What is throwing me off the most is that I default to thinking that any nested for loop is going to be O(n^2), which doesn't seem to be uncommon, but seems to not be the case every time.

Could someone please advise if I am on the right track with my suggestion? How would you break this down?

```
class Solution:
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
        
        countDict = {}
        
        frequency = [[] for i in range(len(nums)+1)]
        
        for j in nums:
            countDict[j] = 1 + countDict.get(j, 0)  
            
        for c, v in countDict.items():
            frequency[v].append(c)
            
        answer = []
        
        for n in range(len(frequency)-1, 0, -1):
            for q in frequency[n]:
                print(frequency[n])
                answer.append(q)
                if len(answer) == k:
                    return answer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frequency` is mapping between frequency-of-elements and the values in the original list. The number of total elements inside of `frequency` is always equal or less than the number of original items in in `nums` (because it is mapping to the unique values in nums).

Even though there is a nested loop, it is still only ever iterating at some `O(C*n)` total values, where `C <= 1` which is equal to `O(n)`.

---

Note, you could clean up this answer fairly easily with some basic helpers. Counter can get you the original mapping for `countDict`. You can use a `defaultdict` to construct `frequency`. Then you can flatten the `frequency` dict values and slice the final result.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict


class Solution:
    def top_k_frequent(self, nums: list[int], k: int) -> list[int]:
        counter = Counter(nums)
        frequency = defaultdict(list)
        for num, freq in counter.items():
            frequency[freq].append(num)

        sorted_nums = []
        for freq in sorted(frequency, reverse=True):
            sorted_nums += frequency[freq]

        return sorted_nums[:k]
```

A fun way to do this in a one liner!

```
class Solution:
    def top_k_frequent(self, nums: list[int], k: int) -> list[int]:
        return sorted(set(nums), key=Counter(nums).get, reverse=True)[:k]
```

Comment: When you reference O(C*n), and that C <= 1, what does C represent?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @dSisk `C` in this case is some constant scalar. Say you loop through a list 2 times, you could say its `O(2*n)` or `O(C*n)` where `C = 2`. By definition this constant doesn't matter because big O describes the growth rate (rather than absolute values). i.e. `O(2n) == O(Cn) == O(n)`. In this case, C would be some value less than or equal to 1, because the number of values iterated is less than the original amount in the `nums` list, however, that value is a constant which is dropped in big O. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954109/why-do-we-ignore-co-efficients-in-big-o-notation

Comment: that makes sense. So even though it is a set of nested for loops, at worst we still only iterate for `len(count)` because frequency will only have up to the amount of elements in count. Right? I think I have the idea. Not sure if I explained my thought process well.

Comment: Sounds like you got it. e.g. `nums [1,1,2,3] -> freq {1: [2, 3], 2: [1]}` which has 3 total values, down from 4 in the original list